# Wireless card tries to connect, but connection fails. Used to work

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager

I used to be able to use my Ubuntu desktop to connect to my Wireless AP.  Then I moved across country and when I finally received my box, the system would no longer connect to the AP.  I have other devices attached to that AP, so I know it works. I have tried to authenticate to a different AP, but that fails. I have taken the wireless NIC card and put it in my laptop, the NIC worked.

The device is able to detect the NIC is there, and uses it to try to authenticate to the network.  I've watched the logs, and when I enter a new AP this is what I see.  Logs from what I've seen below.

My AP is a Netgear and my NIC is a Edimax.

I've run out of ideas, any suggestions of what else I could try.

```
lestat@france:/var/log$ tail -f auth.log syslog
==> auth.log <==
Jan 27 13:17:08 france sudo:       lestat : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/etc/NetworkManager/system-onnections ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/less FRITZ!Box 7330
Jan 27 13:17:08 france sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by estat(uid=1000)
Jan 27 13:17:38 france sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jan 27 13:27:04 france polkitd(authority=local): Unregistered Authentication Agent for nix-session:/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session1 (system bus name :1.32, object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Jan 27 13:27:37 france lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-autologin:session): session opened for user lestat by (uid=0)
Jan 27 13:27:37 france lightdm: pam_ck_connector(lightdm-autologin:session): nox11 mode, ignoring PAM_TTY :0
Jan 27 13:27:38 france polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session1 (system bus name :1.27 [/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1], object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Jan 27 13:27:41 france dbus[758]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.43" (uid=1000 pid=1583 comm="/usr/lib/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-ser") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" error name="(unset)"   requested_reply="0" destination=":1.15" (uid=0 pid=1171 comm="/usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon ")
Jan 27 14:17:01 france CRON[2021]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jan 27 14:17:01 france CRON[2021]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
==> syslog <==
Jan 27 14:37:31 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Jan 27 14:37:31 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Jan 27 14:37:31 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Jan 27 14:37:31 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Jan 27 14:37:31 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Jan 27 14:37:31 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Jan 27 14:37:31 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jan 27 14:37:31 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): access point 'Orleans2000' has security, but secrets are required.
Jan 27 14:37:31 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Jan 27 14:37:31 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Jan 27 14:38:17 france NetworkManager[796]: get_secret_flags: assertion `is_secret_prop (setting, secret_name, error)' failed
Jan 27 14:38:17 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Jan 27 14:38:17 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Jan 27 14:38:17 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Jan 27 14:38:17 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Jan 27 14:38:17 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Jan 27 14:38:17 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Jan 27 14:38:17 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jan 27 14:38:17 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): connection 'Orleans2000' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Jan 27 14:38:17 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Config: added 'ssid' value 'Orleans2000'
Jan 27 14:38:17 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jan 27 14:38:17 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Jan 27 14:38:17 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Jan 27 14:38:17 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Config: added 'psk' value '<omitted>'
Jan 27 14:38:17 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Jan 27 14:38:17 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Jan 27 14:38:17 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
Jan 27 14:38:17 france wpa_supplicant[1024]: Trying to authenticate with c4:3d:c7:64:0d:25 (SSID='Orleans2000' freq=2437 MHz)
Jan 27 14:38:17 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jan 27 14:38:18 france kernel: [ 4259.084194] wlan0: authenticate with c4:3d:c7:64:0d:25 (try 1)
Jan 27 14:38:18 france wpa_supplicant[1024]: Trying to associate with c4:3d:c7:64:0d:25 (SSID='Orleans2000' freq=2437 MHz)
Jan 27 14:38:18 france kernel: [ 4259.086363] wlan0: authenticated
Jan 27 14:38:18 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jan 27 14:38:18 france kernel: [ 4259.110689] wlan0: associate with c4:3d:c7:64:0d:25 (try 1)
Jan 27 14:38:18 france kernel: [ 4259.114336] wlan0: RX AssocResp from c4:3d:c7:64:0d:25 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
Jan 27 14:38:18 france kernel: [ 4259.114340] wlan0: associated
Jan 27 14:38:18 france wpa_supplicant[1024]: Associated with c4:3d:c7:64:0d:25
Jan 27 14:38:18 france kernel: [ 4259.127405] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
Jan 27 14:38:18 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Jan 27 14:38:18 france wpa_supplicant[1024]: WPA: Key negotiation completed with c4:3d:c7:64:0d:25 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Jan 27 14:38:18 france wpa_supplicant[1024]: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to c4:3d:c7:64:0d:25 completed (auth) [id=0 id_str=]
Jan 27 14:38:18 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Jan 27 14:38:18 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'Orleans2000'.
Jan 27 14:38:18 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Jan 27 14:38:18 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Jan 27 14:38:18 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Jan 27 14:38:18 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jan 27 14:38:18 france dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.1-ESV-R4
Jan 27 14:38:18 france dhclient: Copyright 2004-2011 Internet Systems Consortium.
Jan 27 14:38:18 france dhclient: All rights reserved.
Jan 27 14:38:18 france dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Jan 27 14:38:18 france dhclient: 
Jan 27 14:38:18 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> dhclient started with pid 2145
Jan 27 14:38:18 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Beginning IP6 addrconf.
Jan 27 14:38:18 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Jan 27 14:38:18 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> (wlan0): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
Jan 27 14:38:18 france dhclient: Listening on LPF/wlan0/80:1f:02:34:32:33
Jan 27 14:38:18 france dhclient: Sending on   LPF/wlan0/80:1f:02:34:32:33
Jan 27 14:38:18 france dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Jan 27 14:38:18 france dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
Jan 27 14:38:21 france dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
Jan 27 14:38:28 france kernel: [ 4269.502234] wlan0: no IPv6 routers present
Jan 27 14:38:28 france dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10
Jan 27 14:38:38 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> (wlan0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
Jan 27 14:38:38 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Jan 27 14:38:38 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
Jan 27 14:38:38 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
Jan 27 14:38:38 france dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14
Jan 27 14:38:52 france dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14
Jan 27 14:39:03 france NetworkManager[796]: <warn> (wlan0): DHCPv4 request timed out.
Jan 27 14:39:03 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> (wlan0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 2145
Jan 27 14:39:03 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Jan 27 14:39:03 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) started...
Jan 27 14:39:03 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
Jan 27 14:39:03 france NetworkManager[796]: <warn> Activation (wlan0) failed for access point (Orleans2000)
Jan 27 14:39:03 france NetworkManager[796]: <warn> Activation (wlan0) failed.
Jan 27 14:39:03 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) complete.
Jan 27 14:39:03 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Jan 27 14:39:03 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
Jan 27 14:39:03 france kernel: [ 4304.436359] wlan0: deauthenticating from c4:3d:c7:64:0d:25 by local choice (reason=3)
Jan 27 14:39:03 france wpa_supplicant[1024]: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 reason=3
Jan 27 14:39:03 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jan 27 14:39:03 france kernel: [ 4304.522687] cfg80211: All devices are disconnected, going to restore regulatory settings
Jan 27 14:39:03 france kernel: [ 4304.522692] cfg80211: Restoring regulatory settings
Jan 27 14:39:03 france kernel: [ 4304.522696] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Jan 27 14:39:03 france kernel: [ 4304.525578] cfg80211: Ignoring regulatory request Set by core since the driver uses its own custom regulatory domain
Jan 27 14:39:03 france kernel: [ 4304.525581] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Jan 27 14:39:03 france kernel: [ 4304.525583] cfg80211:     (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Jan 27 14:39:03 france kernel: [ 4304.525585] cfg80211:     (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jan 27 14:39:03 france kernel: [ 4304.525587] cfg80211:     (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jan 27 14:39:03 france kernel: [ 4304.525588] cfg80211:     (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jan 27 14:39:03 france kernel: [ 4304.525590] cfg80211:     (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jan 27 14:39:03 france kernel: [ 4304.525592] cfg80211:     (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Jan 27 14:39:06 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Auto-activating connection 'Orleans2000'.
Jan 27 14:39:06 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) starting connection 'Orleans2000'
Jan 27 14:39:06 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Jan 27 14:39:06 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Jan 27 14:39:06 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Jan 27 14:39:06 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Jan 27 14:39:06 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Jan 27 14:39:06 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Jan 27 14:39:06 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jan 27 14:39:06 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): access point 'Orleans2000' has security, but secrets are required.
Jan 27 14:39:06 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Jan 27 14:39:06 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Jan 27 14:39:06 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Jan 27 14:39:06 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Jan 27 14:39:06 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
Jan 27 14:39:06 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Jan 27 14:39:06 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Jan 27 14:39:06 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Jan 27 14:39:06 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jan 27 14:39:06 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): connection 'Orleans2000' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Jan 27 14:39:06 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Config: added 'ssid' value 'Orleans2000'
Jan 27 14:39:06 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jan 27 14:39:06 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Jan 27 14:39:06 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Jan 27 14:39:06 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Config: added 'psk' value '<omitted>'
Jan 27 14:39:06 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Jan 27 14:39:06 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> Config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Jan 27 14:39:06 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jan 27 14:40:06 france NetworkManager[796]: <warn> Activation (wlan0/wireless): association took too long.
Jan 27 14:40:06 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
Jan 27 14:40:06 france NetworkManager[796]: <warn> Activation (wlan0/wireless): asking for new secrets
Jan 27 14:40:06 france NetworkManager[796]: <warn> Couldn't disconnect supplicant interface: This interface is not connected.
Jan 27 14:40:06 france NetworkManager[796]: <warn> Couldn't disconnect supplicant interface: This interface is not connected.
Jan 27 14:40:09 france NetworkManager[796]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface stat   e: scanning -> inactive
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received the answer of how to fix my problem on another forum. ([reference](http://ubuntuforums.org/newthread.php?do=postthread&f=336))

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r) linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms  
wget https://realtek-8188cus-wireless-drivers-3444749-ubuntu-1304.googlecode.com/files/rtl8192cu-tjp-dkms_1.6_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i rtl8192cu-tjp-dkms_1.6_all.deb
echo "blacklist rtl8192cu" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```